# Delete duplicate tuples from list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hi i have a list of list of tuples

```
a = [[('bring', 'VBG'), ('puffy', 'NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS'), ('back', 'RB')], [('droopy','NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS')]]
```

Now i want to remove redundant tuples, means output should be like

```
a = [[('bring', 'VBG'), ('puffy', 'NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS'), ('back', 'RB')], [('droopy', 'NN')]]
```

`tuple ('eye', 'NNS')` has been removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sets`:

One-liner:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [ [y for y in x if y not in seen and not seen.add(y)] for x in a]
[[('bring', 'VBG'), ('puffy', 'NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS'), ('back', 'RB')], [('droopy', 'NN')]]
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
>>> a = [[('bring', 'VBG'), ('puffy', 'NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS'), ('back', 'RB')], [('droopy','NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS')]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> out_lis = []
for x in a:
    temp = []
    for y in x:
        if y not in seen:
            seen.add(y)
            temp.append(y)
    out_lis.append(temp)
...     
>>> out_lis
[[('bring', 'VBG'), ('puffy', 'NN'), ('eyes', 'NNS'), ('back', 'RB')], [('droopy', 'NN')]]
```

Comment: Hi Ashwini i have got this list tagged = [('the', 'DT'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('sees', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cat', 'NN')] and wants the string back means " The dog sees the cat".

Comment: @RahulRanjan how is that related to this question?

Comment: No i am just asking to you.

Comment: @RahulRanjan Don't ask unrelated question in comments, post a new question instead. `" ".join([x[0] for x in tagged])`

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, so i was unaware about it, In future i will follow your suggestion.